# I need to know information from an old German birth certificate

Tags: handwriting, kurrent

I need to know some information about my grandpa from an old German birth certificate shown below. He was born in Bochum.

The birth certificate  is written in Sütterlin and I cannot read this type of writing.

[image]

[image][image][image]

Comment: The question is an individual service request, not a learning or understanding topic, therefor not suited to help anybody else with similar issues which would be the case if asking for individual characters, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! I really appreciate it. I'm excited! I will upload another photos from other parts of the certificate that i dont understand

Comment: @SoniaNitka, consider asking such questions on genealogy.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok i will . Thanks !!!!

Comment: I think it's on topic according to https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/579/are-questions-on-reading-of-old-handwritings-on-topic & https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1275/sind-fragen-%c3%bcber-die-entschl%c3%bcsselung-von-schriften-auch-handschriften-on-topic

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Obviously someone was faster than me but as I have transcribe it too and as I came to a similar result I will post my answer too.

> Bochum, den 8. September 1925
>
> Gemäß einer von dem Kreisgericht zu Swiecie (Schwetz) in Polen am 5. Februar 1923 aufgenommen Verhandlung hat der Landwirt Konstantijn Vitka, polnischer Staatsangehöriger, wohnhaft in Lniano, Kreis Swiecie (Schwetz) in Polen zu dem nebenbezeichneten Kinde mit Vornamen
>
> "Franz"
>
> seine Vaterschaft anerkannt und mit der Mutter des Kindes am 17. Oktober 1921 vor dem Standesbeamten in Lniano die Ehe geschlossen.
>
> Der Standesbeamte
>
> In Vertretung:

I can also confirm that the village Lniano really exists in Poland.

And here is actually the translation of the text:

> Bochum, September 8, 1925
>
> According to a hearing begun by the district court of Swiecie (Schwetz) in Poland on February 5, 1923, the farmer Konstantijn Vitka, a Polish citizen residing in Lniano, in the district of Swiecie (Schwetz) in Poland, has recognized his paternity to the beside-mentioned child with the given name
>
> "Franz"
>
> and has married to the mother of the child on October 17, 1921 before the registrar in Lniano.
>
> The registrar
>
> In representation:

Okay so here is the transcription of the first part of the document:

> Nr. 756
>
> Bochum am 10. April 1918
>
> Vor dem unterzeichneten Standesbeamten machte heute die Direktion der Provinzial Hebammenlehranstalt hierselbst die schriftliche Anzeige, daß von der unverehelichten Näherin Wladislawa Roencki(?), katholischer Religion, wohnhaft zu Bochum Hunscheidtstraße 53, zu Bochum in der Hebammenlehranstalt, am fünften April des Jahres tausend neunhundert achtzehn nachmittags um sechs ein halb Uhr ein Knabe geboren worden sei und daß das Kind den Vornamen Franz erhalten habe.
>
> Vorstehend 15 Druckworte gelöscht
>
> Der Standesbeamte.
>
> In Vertretung

And this is the translation:

> No. 756
>
> Bochum on April 10, 1918
>
> Before the undersigned registrar, the directorate of the provincial midwifery institute today made a written report that the unmarried seamstress Wladislawa Roencki(?), of Catholic religion, residing at Bochum Hunscheidtstrasse 53, has given birth to a boy at the midwifery institute at Bochum, on the fifth of April of the year nine thousand one hundred and eighteen at six-thirty in the afternoon  and that the child was given the first name Franz.
>
> Above 15 printed words deleted
>
> The registrar.
>
> In representation

I had difficulties to read the last name of the mother. So forgive me please if I misspelled it. But maybe someone else could help with that.

Comment: Small typos: [1] "polnische**r**"; [2] The accent mark in "Świecie" is absent, so the transcription should read "**S**wiecie".

Comment: I corrected typo [1]. [2] is not really a typo it was on purpose. Even though the original version from the handwriting is not with an accent mark the official writing nowadays is Świecie. But of course you could argue that I should transcribe it as it is written in the original.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! I really  appreciate it. I'm excited! I will upload another photos from other parts of the certificate that i dont understand

Comment: I uploaded three more photos here if you can help me again. Thank you very much!! Sonia.

Comment: You are very welcome Sonia. It was really fun to do it. I just added to the answer the rest of the transcription and translation.

Comment: Serious genealogists prefer that we not “correct” primary sources.

Comment: Okay, upon request I changed Świecie to Swiecie. I am just a newbie in this field. But I hope it was at least helpful what I did.

Answer (score 9):

I am particularly non-confident with the Polish names, everything German can more easily be inferred from context.
It should also be noted that the writing is in some places a mixture of Sütterlin with modern handwriting (varying shapes of "z" and "e").

*Bochum, den 8. September 1925*

*Gemäß einer von dem Kreisgericht zu Świecie (Schwetz)
in Polen am 5. Februar 1923
aufgenommenen Verhandlung hat der Landwirt
Konstantijan(?) Vitka, polnischer
Staatsangehöriger, wohnhaft in 
Lniano(?), Kreis Świecie (Schwetz) in Polen zu dem
nebenbezeichneten Kinde
mit Vornamen*

*"Franz"*

*seine Veterschaft anerkannt
und mit der Mutter des Kindes am 17. Oktiber 1921
vor dem Standesbeamten in Lniano(?) die Ehe geschlossen.*

*Der Standesbeamte*

*In Vertretung*

Comment: Thank you very much !!! I really appreciate it. I'm excited! I will upload another photos from other parts of the certificate that i dont understand –

Comment: I uploaded three more photos here if you can help me again. Thank you very much!!